# Error com JSONP e Jersey 2.4.1

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, rest, jersey-2.0

My Provider:

```
@Provider
@Path("/alunos")
public class AlunoProvider {

        private AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO();

        @GET
        @JSONP(callback = "eval", queryParam = "jsonpCallback")
        @Produces({"application/javascript","application/json"})            
        public JsonObject getAll() {
                dao.beginTransaction();
                List<Aluno> listaDeAlunos = dao.findAll();
                dao.closeTransaction();

                final JsonArrayBuilder arrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
                for (Aluno aluno : listaDeAlunos) {
                        JsonObjectBuilder b = Json.createObjectBuilder();
                        b.add("id", aluno.getId());
                        b.add("nome", aluno.getNome());
                        arrayBuilder.add(b);
                }

                JsonObjectBuilder r = Json.createObjectBuilder();
                r.add("result", arrayBuilder);
                return r.build();
        }
}
```

And the result is here:

http://lazaro.lazaropj.cloudbees.net/REST/alunos

My JS client:

```
var rootURL = "http://lazaro.lazaropj.cloudbees.net/REST/alunos";


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", url: rootURL,  dataType: "jsonp",
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-origin', 'true');            
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, msg, erro){
                console.log(erro);
            }
        });
```

I think the error may be in requisition. I tried to put Accepts application / javascript in AJAX function but without success. Problem may be in the Jersey API?

Comment: I see that you are, probably, Brazilian. There's a BR version of StackOverflow. Go check it. You are allowed to post in Portuguese there. http://br.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You specified `jsonpCallback` as your callback queryparam, therefore you will need to instruct jquery to use it.

```
var rootURL = "http://lazaro.lazaropj.cloudbees.net/REST/alunos?jsonpCallback=??";
```

Your `beforeSend` and `error` callbacks will be ignored since this is a jsonp request.

An alternative is to have your api listen for the `callback` param instead:

```
@JSONP(callback = "eval", queryParam = "callback")
```

Comment: I do not know if I did well. You are telling me to put the same value in the callback QueryParam?

That's what I did and looked like this:

`@ JSONP (callback = "eval", QueryParam = "callback")`

and URL:

`var RootURL = "http://lazaro.lazaropj.cloudbees.net/REST/alunos?callback =?"; `

But it did not work, kept the same.

Comment: it should have been `?callback=??`, not `?callback =?` I'm not familiar with Jersey, so i'm basing that off the documentation. I'm not sure what the first parameter is for, make sure it's supposed to be "eval"

Comment: I tried this:

`var rootURL  = "http://lazaro.lazaropj.cloudbees.net/REST/alunos?eval =?";`

But still no success. 'm Already desperate